# how to load another page when clicking a button in another page and pass values to the loaded page in jquery?

Tags: php, ajax

I have a button in a page. On clicking the button it should go to another page and that page should be viewed. Also I want to pass some values to the second page when the button is clicked and display the passed values in the second page.

I have written a code in ajax but it is not working.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".chk").click(function(){

if($('input.checkin:checked').val()){



         var apikey = '60CF3C2oh7D+Q+aHDoHt88aEdfdflIjFZdlmsgApfpvg8GXu+W8qr7bKM33cM3';
         var password = 'fHdfvxk';
         var endpoint = 1;
         var method = 'ProcessPayment';

         var dataString = 'APIKey='+apikey+'&APIPassword='+password+'&ddlSandbox='+endpoint+'&ddlMethod='+endpoint;



          $.ajax({


                type: "POST",
                url: "responsive.php",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                success: function(result){




                }
        });


    //window.location.href= 'http://localhost/m/responsive.php';

    }
    else{

        alert("Please Accept the terms and conditions and continue further!!!!");

    }




}); });

</script>
```

I have written a code in ajx when button click, but it will only pass the values to that page. But the page cannot be viewd. Can anyone suggest a solution for this ?

Comment: Hey.. Not like that !! I want the control to go the page responsive.php and need to view the page responsive.php which has a form to fill some details ..

Comment: the alert should help you to see if you get a response or a error. You can make a popup dialog with jquery and inside the popup you can include the form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using ajax you can redirect to the page.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

    $(".chk").click(function(){

    if($('input.checkin:checked').val()){



             var apikey = '60CF3C2oh7D+Q+aHDoHt88aEdfdflIjFZdlmsgApfpvg8GXu+W8qr7bKM33cM3';
             var password = 'fHdfvxk';
             var endpoint = 1;
             var method = 'ProcessPayment';

             //var dataString = 'APIKey='+apikey+'&APIPassword='+password+'&ddlSandbox='+endpoint+'&ddlMethod='+endpoint;
            // use  location href instead of ajax 
             window.location.href = "responsive.php?APIKey='+apikey+'&APIPassword='+password+'&ddlSandbox='+endpoint+'&ddlMethod='+endpoint;
        }
        else{
            alert("Please Accept the terms and conditions and continue further!!!!");
        }

    });
 });
    </script>
```

Comment: the url is coming like this :http://localhost/mysticmountain/responsive.php?APIKey=%27+apikey+%27&APIPassword=%27+password+%27&ddlSandbox=%27+endpoint+%27&ddlMethod=%27+endpoint

Comment: y is it like that ?

Comment: You just need to pass variable values carefully..use proper concatenation

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126499/discussion-between-lena-and-nitin).